# Replace a line containing a special character with nan using textscan in matlab

Tags: matlab, textscan

I am trying to read a file using textscan containing following lines

1.0 2.0 3.0 ? 6.0 5.0

11.0 12.0 13.0 15.0 16.0 15.0

21.0 22.0 23.0 25.0 26.0 25.0

31.0 32.0 33.0 ? 36.0 35.0

How can I replace the question marks with nan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried doing `textscan` with `%s %s %s %s %s %s` and using `str2double` to convert the resulting cell array to numbers

```
f = fopen('file.txt');
raw = textscan(f, '%s %s %s %s %s %s');
data = [];
for k = 1:6
    data = [data str2double(raw{k})];
end
```

Comment: it shouldn't stop reading because '?' is a valid string, i.e. %s. I edited in a code example.

Comment: have you tried the code? it does read question mark as `nan`. that's what the `str2double` part is doing. why don't you try it in matlab by typing `str2double('?')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use TEXTSCAN and specify 'TreatAsEmpty' as '?'.